# Android Async doinbackaground data to onpostexecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need some help with taking results from doinbackground to onpostexecute. The results are in the form of JSONArray. I want to populate two textviews in the UI through onpostexecute. There is no error in the code but nothing happens as it seems inpostexecute is not getting called. Please help. I have looked at several similar questions here and tried many things but unable to get it to work..thanks in advance. Please note **private static final String TAG_LATEST_SCORES = "cricket_scores";**

```
    class PostScores extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewScoreupdatescricketActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Posting LiveScore Updates..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(JSONArray... args) {

        String runs1 = runs.getText().toString();
        String wicket1 = wicket.getText().toString();
        String overs1 = over.getText().toString();
        String rr1 = rr.getText().toString();
        String team_name = null;
        String bat1;
        if (innings.isChecked() == false) {
            bat1 = "1";
            team_name = bat.getText().toString();

        } else {
            bat1 = "2";
            team_name = bat.getText().toString();
        }
        if (rr1.equals("NA")) {
            rr1 = "0";
        }

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("runs", runs1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wickets", wicket1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("overs", overs1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rr", rr1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bat", bat1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("team_name", team_name));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {

                latest_scores = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LATEST_SCORES);


            } else {

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
        return latest_scores;

    }
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray latest_sc) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < latest_sc.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = latest_sc.getJSONObject(i);

            String wickets = c.getString(TAG_WICKETS);
            String runs = c.getString(TAG_RUNS);
            score_inngs1.setText(wickets + runs);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure the json array has data ??  try to log it as string to check it   and feed me

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I have updated the complete doinbackground code. Before I simplified it to post  it here...JSONArray = {"success":1,"cricket_scores":[{"runs":"30","innings":"1","overs":"1","wickets":"8","team_name":"xcvxcvcxv"}]}

Comment: in this json you have jsonarray called cricket_scores you need to fetch it from json object and extract its data as string

Comment: Can you please explain your suggestion little bit?

Comment: this element in json called cricket_scores where you reference in your code ??

Comment: private static final String TAG_LATEST_SCORES = "cricket_scores"; In the very beginning

Comment: sorry, i didn't see it ,  it doesn't included in code format  , actually i tried your code and it work with me well , i suggest you Log the json in  onPostExecute  and feed me

Comment: No worries..thanks..in onPostExecute. I added **Log.d("Create Response", "in post execute");** and this did not show up in logcat.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It was a case of misplaced bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your brackets. After your definition of `doInBackground`, you have an extra bracket - that one closes off your `PostScores` class, so your `onPostExecute` method is defined as a member of whatever class is enclosing `PostScores`, if any.

Also, you'll need to `@Override` the `AsyncTask` methods to provide your own implementation.